# Getting the values of variables in a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Note: this is my first attempt at a chrome extension so go easy and I really appreciate any help I can get.

So I am trying to make a chrome extension that can solve the maths problem generated by the website.

This would require adding together n1 and n2 which are randomly generated.

```
<div class="captcha-wrapper">
  <div>
   <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="question-captcha">
   <span>=</span>
   <input type="text" id="answer-captcha">
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 var n1 = Math.round(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
 var n2 = Math.round(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
 $("#question-captcha").val(n1 + " + " + n2);
 $('#AddToCart').click(function(){
   if (eval($("#question-captcha").val()) != $("#answer-captcha").val()) {
     alert('That CAPTCHA was incorrect!');
     $("#answer-captcha").focus();
     return false;
    }
  });
 });
</script>

<button type="submit" name="add" id="answer" class="btn">
     <span id="answertext">Answer</span>
</button>
```

I have worked out how to input values into the answer-captcha box however I don't know if it would be even possible to find the values of n1 and n2 which I would like to add together because they would be randomly generated and different each time the site is loaded.

Appreciate any help :)

Comment: Get #question-captcha text, split by +, parseFloat, and sum.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I am very new to this and unsure of how to go about doing that

Comment: I's not clear what the problem is. Currently the question looks like a typical "I don't know anything so do it for me plz". It's not even clear whether you know JavaScript. The generic advice is to start with a tutorial or documentation. See also the links in [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-chrome-extension/info).